# Homeomorphism from $S^1$ to $\mathbb R$

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to find a homeomorphism taking$$[0,1] \times S^1 \rightarrow \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}: 1 \leq \|(x,y)\| \leq 2\}$$

I was thinking that a homeomorphism from $S^1$ to $\mathbb{R}$ gives the $x$ then $y = 1+t$ ,  $t\in [0,1]$. Would do it but i'm struggling.

Comment: What do you mean a homeomorphism from $\mathbb{S}^1$ to $\mathbb{R}$? There is no such thing!

Comment: @busman : The fact that there's no such thing is not an occasion to ask what is meant?  If you didn't know what is meant, then you wouldn't be able to say that there's no such thing.

Comment: Clearly you mean $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\colon $ (etc.)

Comment: @MichaelHardy I know what a homeomorphism is and why there is none between, for instance, a compact space and one that is not (as with this case). I mean, not that my speech was completely literal or without any implicit language. Your question is certainly most strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean an homeomorphism from $S^1 \times [0,1] \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ to $ \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}: 1 \leq \|(x,y)\| \leq 2\} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ then I think the function

$f(x,y,t)=((t+1)x,(t+1)y)$ ; $t\in [0,1]$, $x^2+y^2=1$

should work.

Comment: $f(x,y,0) =(0,0) $ and so is not in the appropriate codomain of your function. For a similar reason, your function is also not injective. (It's an easy fix, though!)

Comment: Thank you. I think its fixed now!

Comment: Thanks, the question left out the $\mathbb{R}^2$ - it must have been a typo.

Answer (score 7):

You're not going to find a homeomorphism from $S^1$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Instead, I suggest drawing the set $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\ |\ 1\leq \|(x,y)\|\leq 2\}$. If you think in terms of polar coordinates, you will very quickly see a natural way to write down a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 3):

There can't be a homeomorphism because if you remove one point from $S^1$ it is still connected but the reals are not.

Comment: Or $S^1$ is compact and $\mathbb{R}$ isn't.

Comment: Or $S^1$ is not contractible and $\mathbb R$ is.

Answer (score 0):

How about $f(t,\theta)=((t(\sqrt2-1)+1)\cos\theta, (t(\sqrt2-1)+1)\sin\theta)$?